# How to access Windows Phone 8.1 system files

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

Is there any possibility how to get access to the  WP8.1 system files (C:/), especially app files? There is a solution for WP 10, but I can not find any evidence about WP 8.1.

Comment: No answer yet? Why? Please give a solution. Have you found out how, Ernest?

Comment: Here is a very good article about that : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758319.aspx